# How to mark APIs as unused in OpenAPI 3.x

Tags: swagger, openapi, springdoc-openui

How to mark APIs as unused in OpenAPI 3.x, when the library is not ready for consumption by other microservices which intend to use the API

Note: Right now, we build a lot of API(s) and they are in various stages of development. Is there a way to annotate this, so that other developers know that there are API(s) which are still work in progress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenAPI specification till 3.1.0 doesn't define a way to describe the maturity level of the API.

There was a [proposal](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1973) about adding `/info/lifecycle` to describe lifecycle and maturity information. But it doesn't seem to get conclusion.

You can define OpenAPI [extension](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/openapi-extensions/) to store the information. Just like the `/info/x-maturity` in [Smart API Specification](https://github.com/SmartAPI/smartAPI-Specification/blob/OpenAPI.next/versions/3.0.0.md#smartapi-fields-3):

> `x-maturity`  enum :  Maturity of the API. Values to use: `development`, `staging`, `production`.

Another way is to represent your API maturity/readiness in the API version. The [semantic versioning](https://semver.org) allows you to append additional labels for pre-release in the version. For example, any developer should know an API with version `1.0.0-alpha.1` or `1.0.0-dev.1` is still work in progress and not ready for use.

> A pre-release version MAY be denoted by appending a hyphen and a
> series of dot separated identifiers immediately following the patch
> version. ...... A pre-release
> version indicates that the version is **unstable** and might not satisfy
> the intended compatibility requirements as denoted by its associated
> normal version. Examples: 1.0.0-alpha, 1.0.0-alpha.1, 1.0.0-0.3.7,
> 1.0.0-x.7.z.92, 1.0.0-x-y-z.–.